# Rolling back action "MariaDB 10.6 (x64) Setup Wizard ended prematurely" when installing MariaDB

Tags: sql, installation, mariadb-10.6

I just tried to install MariaDB 10.6.5 (x64) on Windows 11

But it keeps showing as below

[Error Installation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLEV9.png)

1. I've tried some possible solutions like doing the command `msiexec /...` in cmd
2. I also want to try this possible solution

   "You need to used regedit.exe to remove the hidden files manually then you will be able to reinstall it again" but I don't understand how.

Can someone give any possible solution or guide me to used regedit.exe to remove the hidden files?

Comment: Can you try: msiexec /i mariadb-10.6.7-winx64.msi /le mariadb.log, and then add the info from mariadb.log to this question?  (I did not have problems installing this version)

Comment: Or can/will you delete this question if install succeed by now, because a later attempt was successful?