# mariadb Setup Wizard ended premature (install error in windows10)

Tags: mariadb

i want to install MariaDB in Windows10.
my pc is x64.
and i download MariaDB server 10.6.7 (x86_64)
and i installed msi file.
but can't success install.. with rolling back action.

and show message this.

---

MariaDB 10.6 (x64) Setup Wizard ended premature

### MariaDB 10.6 (x64) Setup Wizard ended prematurely because of an error. Your system has not been modified. To install this program at a later time, run Setup Wizard again. click the finish button to exit the Setup Wizard

i tried

```
regsvr32 C:\Windows\System32\vbscript.dll
regsvr32 vbscript.dll
```

and i tried install again visual C++ new version again,
and i tried update window.

but everything not worked for me..
give me solution, please

Comment: same question, but from 10 days ago (and asked by someone else): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70982771/rolling-back-action-mariadb-10-6-x64-setup-wizard-ended-prematurely-when-ins

Comment: Can you try: `msiexec /i mariadb-10.6.7-winx64.msi /le mariadb.log`, and then add the info from mariadb.log to this question? (using [edit])

Comment: @Luuk i tried 'msiexec /i mariadb-10.6.7-winx64.msi /le mariadb.log' and i success install.. i don't know what happened. i want to share solution, but i don't know why successed. i just install with this commend

Comment: It succeeded because it's Windows.... (or because you might have done a reboot since your previous attempt)

Comment: @Luuk i tried maybe 8 hour, and i reboot 5~6times. but can't install. and successed with your commend msiexec.. i don't know what happened

Comment: OK, but finally it worked, so ..... 

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue with 10.7.3

It was due to Windows system variable `TMPDIR` incorrectly set to a non-existant directory, causing "innodb fatal error" during database initialization.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and for me it seems the problem was the system clock. It was for some reason set to far into the future, the 2070s. MariaDB successfully installed once we corrected the system date.